# Proxy HTTP to HTTPS using Node

Tags: node.js, http, proxy, http-proxy

How can I proxy a 3rd party website from HTTP to HTTPS using NodeJS?

For example, I would like my users to access http://somesite.com as https://localhost:8001

I have tried using http-proxy library, following their example in HTTP -> HTTPS section, but all I get is empty response error.

Comment: It would be helpful you share what you've tried. Only then can we figure out what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

`http-proxy` module should work. Try below example which proxies `https://google.com`

```
var https = require('https'),
httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

//
// Create a HTTP Proxy server with a HTTPS target
//
httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: 'https://google.com',
  agent  : https.globalAgent,
  secure : false,
  headers: {
    host: 'google.com'
  }
}).listen(8011);
```

A sample git repo is [here](https://github.com/pktippa/stackoverflow-questions/tree/master/58305413).